# Can you run a raster calculation on the output of a raster calculation?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

Using QGis 2.16.3, I'm trying to perform a multi stage raster calculation. Trying to do the whole calculation using brackets to subset parts causes a memory issue; however running a raster calculation on the output of a previous raster calculation results in all pixels incorrectly taking on the same value.

For example:

`(0.56*"Band3@1")+2`

Returns a .tif file with pixels ranging from 402.922 to 4863.86 whereas

`0.56*"Band3@1"`

saved as Band3_R.tif and then using a second raster calculation of

`"Band3_R@1"+2`

returns a .tif file with all pixels being 2.

It is the same regardless of what operation I attempt on the output (addition, subtraction, multiplication or division).

Can you run a raster calculation on the output of a raster calculation? If so, how?

Comment: Perhaps a bug? I do not have this problem with QGIS 2.18.2 for Win7 64-bit. Could you try installing a newer version?

Comment: Must have been a bug - installed QGIS 2.18.13 and now works. Thanks @Joseph. Didn't even consider that as the cause - still rather new to GIS

Comment: Nice one! Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

It must have been a bug - Updating to QGIS 2.18.13 solved the problem.